# How to test a web service where there is time lag?

Tags: web-services, testing, soap, curl

I am supposed to test a web service which will create an account on the server side.

However, due to the architecture reason, the SOAP call will not return a message for now. So I have to issue another `cURL` command to test if account has been created successfully.

The problem is: the account creation time takes ~ 50 seconds to finish. If I want to automate the process, what's the best practice to issue the `cURL` command? Should I always wait for ~ 50 seconds or more? Or should I contiguously send `cURL` until the account's been created/reached a max wait time(say 90 seconds)?

Any comments are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to use curl? Java EE JAX-WS supports asynchronous service calls that allow callbacks. With that, you won't have to poll like you're doing with curl. You will be notified instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't (or don't want to) change the web service, I would choose a combination of both.

> Should I always wait for ~ 50 seconds or more?
>   Or should I contiguously send cURL until the account's been created/reached a max wait time(say 90 seconds)?

I would wait a `startingTime` seconds (say `50`), and from there on make a call every `retryTime` seconds (say `10`), up to `maxTries` calls (say `4`). That is:

```
00:00 - call the createAccount
00:50 - issue first cURL command to check if account was created
if not created
01:00 - issue another cURL command to check if account was created
if not created
01:10 - issue another cURL command to check if account was created
if not created
01:20 - issue another cURL command to check if account was created
if not created: consider the creation has failed
```

---

On a side note, why do you need to wait 50s?

Is the creating operation so slow or are you using an asynchronous creation system?

If you are using an asynchronous creation system and do can change the web service, you could:

- Use the **[Asynchronous Web Service Invocation capabilities of JAX-WS 2.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/19/asynchronous-jax-ws-web-services.html)**;
- Or... make the `createAccount` service return a ticket number (an integer) and then create a `checkTicket` method, which would allow you to check if your creation call has been processed.